# how to build ios app with xcode for other certificate/store-account

Tags: ios, xcode, build, certificate

I have my own developer certificate and now I want to compile/build an app for a customer with his own (single user) account. how could I build an ios app with xcode for other certificates?
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a provisioning profile from his dev account.. using keychain in your system..

Then when archiving ..select the customer distribution profile for the app.

That's it

Comment: which account..?if i make a app for a client.. i test it on my device using my developer profile.. but archive it using the provisioning profile created using his account.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know a way on how to do it the programmatically way. But you can do it really easy: If you are making the app for a customer, I assume he pays you for the rights to the app including source code. So just develop it. And when it is finished you send him the source code and he compiles it on his own and publishes it.

Or he sends you his certificate (if this is possible).

Comment: the code is not sold with the app. he sent me the provisioning certificate. but to compile the app I think I also need the developer certificate...

Comment: Then he has to send it to you. I couldn't think of any other way.